# validation only for type word english or persian or number?

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate, jquery

how is validation only for type word english or persian or number, each separate in input?
i not want use of plugin.

only type english -> hello
only type persian -> سلام
only type number -> 123123

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [English only](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/4mJZg/)

```
var only_english = 'abcdAbDKDk',
    mixed = 'سلامaaSDSD';

if (/[^A-Za-z]/g.test(only_english)) {
    alert('"only_english" contains characters other than English');
} else {
    alert('"only_english" contains only English characters');
}

if (/[^A-Za-z]/g.test(mixed)) {
    alert('"mixed" contains characters other than English');
} else {
    alert('"mixed" contains only English characters');
}
```

2. [Persian only](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/m2Db3/)

```
var only_persian = 'سلام',
    mixed = 'سلامaaSDSD';

if (/[^\u0600-\u06FF]/g.test(only_persian)) {
    alert('"only_persian" ontains characters other than Persian');
} else {
    alert('"only_persian" ontains only Persian characters');
}

if (/[^\u0600-\u06FF]/g.test(mixed)) {
    alert('"mixed" contains characters other than Persian');
} else {
    alert('"mixed" contains only Persian characters');
}
```

3. [Only numbers](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/fnxe3/)

```
var only_numbers = '12334',
    mixed = '3124adqad';

if (/[^0-9]/g.test(only_numbers)) {
    alert('"only_numbers" does not contain only numbers');
} else {
    alert('"only_numbers" contains only numbers');
}

if (/[^0-9]/g.test(mixed)) {
    alert('"mixed" does not contain only numbers');
} else {
    alert('"mixed" contains only numbers');
}
```

Comment: only type english -> hello, 
only type persian -> سلام, 
only type number -> 123123 -> this is example. all word persian. all word english. all numbers.

Comment: @Me hdi: I am giving you an example, too. You can obviously change the strings to test against. _"all word persian. all word english."_ What do you mean? You want to validate if the input is a well spelled English word?

Comment: @Me hdi: Doesn't have to do with jQuery. jQuery is used for DOM manipulation, this is plain vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RegularExpressionValidator
and set it's validationExpression to :
Only English = [A-Za-z]+
Only Number =\d+

Comment: Please explain more and give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var only_persian = 'salam 1ایران';

if (/^[A-Za-z\u0600-\u06FF\s]*$/.test(only_persian)) {
    alert(true);
} else {
    alert(false);
}
```

Comment: You should improve your answer explaining it a little

Comment: Maybe you can explain more to the OP what it is you are doing? The use of regex? =)